# Prevent the backend url to be read from url

Tags: laravel, url, content-management-system, backend

I know title is a bit confusing but I will explain here instead.

I have an CMS for users to insert their own information. So inside the page that is an URL field: [image: URL field]

Which mean users are able to insert whatever format such as

1. https://backend.com
2. [www.backend.com](http://www.backend.com)
3. backend.com

and this url will put in a button on frontend. Once clicked on it, will redirect to the url accordingly.

[image]

Now the issue I'm facing is 3rd point (backend.com) format. If user key in "backend,com" and click on this button on frontend, they will redirected to `https://mywebsite.com/backend.com`. By right should redirect to "backend.com" instead.

I'm using Laravel and use {{$url}} to read data from database. Simplified code below:

```
//html
<a id="book-submit">Book</a>

//javascript
$("#book-submit").on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        type: "POST",
        data:{
         },success :function(response) {
            window.location.href='{{$url}}';
        }
    })
});

//mysql
$check= DB::connection('mysql_api')->table('course')->select('url')->first();
$data['url'] = $check->url;
```

Is that any method to prevent this? Hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly the problem is. Where does you frontend show `https://mywebsite.com/backend.com`? why is it a problem? What are you expecting?

Comment: I have a button to read this url from backend. So if user inserted "backend.com", it suppose will redirected to "backend.com" if I click on the button. But I redirected to "https://mywebsite.com/backend.com" instead

Comment: are you calling url('backend.com')? Because that function prepends your sites url, to whatever you give it.

Comment: @Eelyn Could you add the code for the button to your question.

Comment: @Remul added. I need to simplified my code because still got other functions

Comment: @KurtFriars I have added the code.

Comment: How is $url populated is what we are asking.

Comment: Through the database backend using MySQL query.

Comment: to refer to other page using "window.location.href" you need http:// or https:// on it, thats why when only backed.com it only redirect to your own server

Comment: @Kelvin you got the point! Is that any other method to replace "window.location.href" so that I can read "backend.com" only?

Comment: i can say no, you need to manipulate your data from database before send it to js

Comment: if like that can only put some validation before insert. Seem like force user to insert http/https, which not a good way. Hmmm

Comment: not forced, but you can use your own logic, if the user doesnt input the http / https you can add manualy, or if the data not include http / https just add that by string concatenation

Comment: @Kelvin will check on backend instead, thank you! Can put in answer part? I will accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refer to another page using `window.location.href` you need `http://` or `https://` on it

1. if your already have data url in your database without `http://` or
   `https://`, you need to manipulate it by your own logic like you
   using `strpos`, or `regex
2. You can validation the user input

For some information, you can use `[FILTER_VALIDATE_URL]` to validate `URL`

See http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php for additional flags